# Microsoft Office Localization

Tags: localization, language, microsoft-office

I have installed a language pack for Microsoft Office 2010 in order to be able to spell check another language. Now the Event Log messages for Microsoft Office are appearing in that language.

> The language of the exception message
>   is determined by the Visual Studio
>   Tools for Office runtime language. For
>   instance, if the end user computer has
>   the Japanese language pack installed,
>   the exception message is written to
>   the event log in Japanese.

However, I only want the language pack to apply to Proofing (spelling, grammar). I want Event Log message to appear in English. How can I change this?